# Fetch time from database and schedule task in Azure at that perticular time

Tags: sql, azure

I am in need of a scheduler which can fetch the time from the database and run a particular piece of code every day at that particular time,i wonder if there is way to do it in Azure,please help

Comment: Hi, thanks for your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is too broad for this site.

Comment: @broor - did the answer help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you might want to use Azure Runbooks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#powershell-runbooks) using Schedules or Azure Logic Apps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure logic app in the following way:

1. Keep monitoring the table(database) for any updated timestamp of schedule. Fetch and store in a variable.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure
2. Use the Delay-Until action and update the value of the timestamp picked in step 1.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-delay#add-the-delay-until-action